# Where can I find the source of this shareholder-detail-table image?

Tags: stocks, ipo

I am reading some news online and found an image in one post. I'd like to know where is the source. It looks like a website.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Which company is this for?

Comment: Seems like a snap of the shareholding page from the financial accounts of the company in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by some detective work (which really wouldn't have been necessary if you'd provided the relevant information in your question) I found this image, or one very like it, in [this page](http://technews.co/2014/06/30/chinas-xunlei-lists-in-u-s-company-value-reaches-us986-million/).

In which case, the source is from Xunlei’s Nasdaq filing documents, as it says in the article, and you can find those yourself [here](http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/company/xunlei-ltd-857196-75531?tab=financials) and in particular the image you reference is from Page 192 of [this document](http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/filing.ashx?filingid=9619357).